# Problema ao subir uma página em React

Tags: react

Estou criando uma página para mim. Instalei o nginx e direcionei o `index.html` para meu projeto feito em React.

Porém ao acessar a página está em branco(Não deveria). O Nginx e o React estão funcionando, pois o título da página está escrito `React App`, e se eu acessar o codigo font da página tudo vai estar lá. Porem ao acessar o código da página me deparo com isso:

```
<script src="/vncsms/MySiteReact/static/js/main.3702ad6a.chunk.js">
```

No meu servidor há uma pasta na raiz chamada `MySiteReact`. o caminho deste arquivo está em `~/MySiteReact/build/static/js`. E não estou entendendo porque o meu site está pegando este caminho para este arquivo. o caminho `vncsms` é meu nick no github, onde é o repositorio. A questão que não entendi porque o React direcionou meus arquivos com meu nick do github.

Meu packge.json do React:

```
{
  "name": "mysite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/vncsms/MySiteReact.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/vncsms/MySiteReact/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/vncsms/MySiteReact#readme",
  "description": ""
}
```

*O Repositorio é privado.

Comment: Como você fez o *build* da sua aplicação ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece por causa da propriedade `homepage` no `package.json`.

Essa é uma funcionalidade do `create-react-app`. Quando ele encontra essa propriedade ele assume esse endpoint como padrão.

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths